# Javascript live animation

Tags: javascript

I'm working on genetic algorithms in Javascript and would need to visualize in real time the solutions provided by the algorithm.

Basically, I need [something like this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/js/genetic-algorithm/GA.html) (when clicking "run")

All my attempts, using DIVs and CSS positioning, or creating SVG end up with a blank screen and browser crash.

Using setInterval to define steps in the render seems a bad idea as it also drastically reduce the algorithm speed.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: There is no code, every attempt of infinite loop failed. I'm looking for advices or ideas, that's the point.

Comment: the failed attempts code would be a great base to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue with the browser crashing can be solved with a proper use of setTimeout, nextTick, setImmediate or requestAnimationFrame, allowing the browser to render the graph before the next calculations.

As I needed some graph rendering as well to display the results, I ended up using [P5.js](https://p5js.org), which is quite awesome.

Comment: You should also have a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout...

Comment: I edited my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use Reactjs. This framework can organize components in real time. I have a project called Game of life, it is like genetic algorithm.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/israelmarmar/pen/vZmWPp)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I can't use ReactJs on this project. Examples i found just seems to use some kind of infinite loop, so I'm quite confused. Really cool example, though !